# Collect values from HashMap into one array using streams api

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a map, containing strings as a key and `ArrayList` as values. I want to use stream api to get as a result all the Arrays from values as one array.

```
Map<Integer,  ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Result: one  `ArrayList<String>` containing all the Strings from value arrays and preferably unique values.

Comment: What did you try so far? What didn't work?

Comment: of course I googled, I just did not find rights words) thanks for the link. I tried flatmap first, but I did not know that it should be List::stream inside.

Comment: @MyFoenix in any case, it can be done with method reference, or `.flatMap(a -> a.stream())` but the method reference in this case is better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to this :

```
List<String> distinctValues = map.values().stream() // Stream<ArrayList<String>>
        .flatMap(List::stream)                      // Stream<String>
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you prefer `ArrayList` as a result, then use :

```
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```